# Show that Möbius transformation $S$ commute with $T$ if $S$ and $T$ have the same fixed point.

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let $T$ be a Möbius Transformation such that $T$ is not the identity. Show that Möbius transformation $S$ commute with $T$ if $S$ and $T$ have the same fixed point.

Here is what I know so far

1) if $T$ has fixed points says $z_1$ and $z_2$ then $S^{-1}TS$ has fixed point $S^{-1}(z_1)$ and $S^{-1}(z_2)$

2) if $T$ is dilation then $0$ and $\infty$ are its only fixed point, but if $T$ is translation then only $\infty$ is its fixed point.

Assume that $S$ and $T$ has the same fixed points $z_1$ and $z_2 $ then by 1)

$S^{-1}TS$ and $T^{-1}ST$ have the same fixed point $S^{-1}(z_1)=T^{-1}(z_1)$ and $S^{-1}(z_2)=T^{-1}(z_2)$

I know that $T$ is not the identity, but I can't assume it is dilation or translation to use 2), because it can also be inverse, right?

I wonder if anyone would please have me a hand from here.

Comment: The group of Mobius transformations acts $2$-transitively (in fact, $3$-transitively) on $\mathbb{C}$, so observation (1) means that given any nonparabolic Mobius transformation $T$ with fixed points, say, $z_1, z_2$, we can choose a transformation $A$ for which $A^{-1}(z_1), A^{-1}(z_2)$ are any two convenient points, which are then precisely the fixed points of $\bar{T} := A T A^{-1}$. Then, it's enough to show the claim for the transformation $\bar{T}$, as $S$ and $T$ commute iff $\bar{S}$ and $\bar{T}$ commute.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain a little bit further please? I'm not sure I understand how you got $\overline S$ and $\overline T$ commute, you let $A=S$?

Comment: Sure, we have $\bar{S} \bar{T} = (ASA^{-1})(ATA^{-1}) = ASTA^{-1} \color{red}{=} ATSA^{-1} = (ATA^{-1})(ASA^{-1}) = \bar{T} \bar{S}$, where the red equality uses that hypothesis that $S, T$ commute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that $S$ and $T$ are two Moebius transformations of the extended $z$-plane $\overline{\Bbb C}$ having the same fixed points $z_1$, $z_2\in{\Bbb C}$, $\>z_1\ne z_2$. The we can introduce "temporarily" in $\overline{\Bbb C}$ a new complex coordinate
$$w:={z-z_1\over z-z_2}\ .$$
The point $z=z_1$ gets the $w$-coordinate $w_1={z_1-z_1\over z-z_2}=0$, and the point $z=z_2$ gets the $w$-coordinate $w_2=\infty$. In terms of this new coordinate both $S$ and $T$ are again given by Moebius expressions, but now the fixed points have $w$-coordinate values $0$ and $\infty$; whence $S$ and $T$ appear as dilations:
$$S(w)=\lambda w, \quad \lambda\ne 1;\qquad T(w)=\mu w,\quad \mu\ne1\ .$$
When expressed in terms of $w$ the two transformations obviously commute; therefore they have to commute as well when expressed in terms of the original coordinate $z$. – A similar argument takes care of the case $z_1\in{\Bbb C}$, $z_2=\infty$.

When $S$ and $T$ both have exactly one fixed point $z_0\in {\Bbb C}$ then we can replace $z_0$ by $w_0=\infty$ as before. Now $S$ appears as
$$S(w)=\alpha w+\beta\ .$$
When $\alpha\ne1$ then $S$ would have a second fixed point $w_2={\beta\over 1-\alpha}$. It follows that $S$ and $T$ are of the form
$$S(w)=w+\beta,\quad\beta\ne0;\qquad T(w)=w+\gamma,\quad \gamma\ne0\ ;$$
whence commute.

Answer (score 2):

I thought about this the other day.

Suppose that

$M_1(z) = \frac{a_1z + b_1}{c_1z + d_1}$ and $M_2(z) = \frac{a_2z + b_2}{c_2z + d_2}$

are Möbius transforms with the same two fixed points $z_0$ and $z_1$.

Then $\;c_1 z^2 + (d_1 - a_1)z - b_1 = c_1(z-z_0)(z-z_1)\;$ and

$\;c_2 z^2 + (d_2 - a_2)z - b_2 = c_2(z-z_0)(z-z_1).$

With $c_1 = kc_2$ for some $k,$ we get $\;b_1 = -kc_2 z_0 z_1 = k b_2 ~~~~~(*),\;$

and $\;d_1 - a_1 = -kc_2 (z_0+z_1) = k(d_2 - a_2) ~~~~~ (**)$.

Now, $M_1(M_2(z)) = \frac{(a_1a_2 + b_1c_2)z + a_1b_2 + b_1d_2}{(c_1a_2 + d_1c_2)z + c_1b_2 + d_1d_2}$

[Using (*)]

$=  \frac{(a_1a_2 + kb_2c_2)z + b_2(a_1+kd_2)}{c_2(ka_2+d_1)z + c_2b_1 + d_2d_1}$

[Using (**) and (*)]

$= \frac{(a_2a_1 + b_2c_1)z + b_1a_2+ b_2d_1}{(c_2 a_1 + c_1d_2)z + c_2b_1 + d_2d_1} = M_2(M_1(z)).$